# Save FORM data on client PC when Internet connection is lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, offline

I need help creating mechanism to save FORM data on Client PC when internet connection is Lost.

For e.g : http://testfunda.com is basically an testing portal where user can appear for exams, it has the functionality where user Submits the exam, **TestFunda** checks first for the Internet connectivity, if the Internet connectivity is Lost then it creates a FORM data file ask to save it on Local machine.

I have no idea how this stuff works, need help for creating such mechanism.
Thanx :)

Comment: I'm thinking the two things they deal with are: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.onLine **and** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage

Comment: @lan i am done with Checking internet connectivity, i am only worried about storing FORM data in a file which can be uploaded after words when Internet comes.

Comment: Oops, I didn't read the part about saving a file to disk. I'm not sure that's available in plain JavaScript yet, so I"m wondering if they use Flash/Java or something. Or maybe I"m forgetting some other feature that allows this

Comment: @lan even i am also thinking what mechanism they've used, coz i am done with creating JSON string using jQuery serialize(), i just want create a file where JSON string stores and ask user to save a file on disk.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer, all thanx to **viralpatel**.

answer: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-zip-file-javascript

in the above i can create zip file inside which i can save any format file like(.txt or .xml ) with data.